# Access a variable made in another IBAction in the same file

Tags: swift, xcode, variables, iboutlet

I've created a variable in one IBAction which saves a string, and I want to be able to call that variable in another IBAction in the same file. How do I define the variable globally so that the other IBAction can call it?

The variable `message` comes from a UIAlertController output, which appears when pressing a button on the View Controller.

```swift
 @IBAction func EditMessage(_ sender: Any) {

let message = Message(message: text)

}

@IBAction func PostArticle(_ sender: Any) {

let parameters = ["title": "subheading", "content": "\(message)"]

}
```

Trying to call the `message` variable from the other IBAction will only give the error:

```
Use of unresolved identifier 'message'
```

Comment: The code doesn't compile anyway. There is another similar error `Use of unresolved identifier 'text'`. And does `Message` conform to `CustomStringConvertible`? If not you'll get a third error.

Comment: `text` was left out of the code snippet as it was not causing the error, thus not needed to reproduce the same error.

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyViewController : UIViewController {

var  message = ""



@IBAction func EditMessage(_ sender: Any) {

 message = Message(message: text)

}

@IBAction func PostArticle(_ sender: Any) {

let parameters = ["title": "subheading", "content": "\(message)"]

}
}
```

Hope it Helps.

Comment: Mishara Only issue... the `message = Message(message: text)` gives off the error `Cannot assign value of type 'Message' to type 'String' ` when going from the empty variable.

Comment: @Samcool236 Could You please  what is this  = Message(message: text)

Comment: @Avinsah Mishara Message is defined in another file called `Message.swift`. Message is as follows:
`class Message: Codable {
    var message:String?
    
    init(message: String) {
        self.message = message
    }

}
`

Answer (score 0):

Make your message variable be accessible to the two IBActions.

Your **Message** function should return a string

`Message(message: String) -> String { 
   // Do something here
   return "sample" 
}`

[Read Swift Function](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Functions.html)